# Query a DB with a String "Male or Female" if neither String is selected return all results

Tags: android, sql, android-room

If a @Query string value doesn't return a result how do you return all the results from the column in Room?

Let's say I have list of students in my database, the database contains a Gender column, the entries in the column can be "Male" or "Female". I want to use one @Query that has the option to display all the students, the male students or the female students.

Reposiotry

```
// Constructor
public Repository(Application application, String gender) {
    this.studentDao = db.StudentDao();
    this.student = studentDAO.getStudents(gender);
}
```

DAO

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM student_table WHERE mStudent =:gender or '%'")
LiveData<List<StudentEntity>> getStudents(String gender or '%male'); 


If Male or Female weren't selected I want to see all the students return in the LiveData<List>.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT st.*
FROM student_table st
WHERE st.mStudent = :gender or :gender NOT IN ('Male', 'Female');
```